# $\mathbb S^3$ parallelizable $\Rightarrow$ "uniform" lattice in $\mathbb S^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Does the fact that the three-sphere is parallelizable imply that one can construct a "uniform" lattice in S^3? By uniform I mean that (assume the number of lattice points is large) any small neighborhood around any lattice point will "look" the same. And when I say look the same I mean distances and angles between nearest lattice points are the same (edit, the lattice need not be locally rectangular)?

I think I came up with a set of points in S^3 that do the job but I'm stuck trying to show the above.

(see post in Physics Forums for set of points [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/set-of-points-in-s-3-way-to-show-spaced-equal-or-not.804205/))

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Parallelizability has nothing to do with that. But if you want uniformly and regularly distributed doints in $S^3$ you can pick the vertices of regular polyhedra.

Comment: One hint that parallelizability has nothing to do with this is that in fact *all* orientable $3$-manifolds are parellelizable.

Comment: I was hoping for a large lattice of points so the polyhedra won't work. So the set of points I defined will not do what I want it to do?  Thank you. Rats %^(

Comment: I have no idea if your points «will do», as I don't really know what exactly you expect from them. :-) Your definition of «look the same» is very close to «are the vertices of a regular polyhedron» so I doubt you can do that at all. If you settle for «approximately the same» I am sure combinatorists have looked at way of putting points in spheres in that way.

Comment: I was wondering if N^3 (N is some large integer) atoms in a three-sphere could form a crystal (close to cubic primitive cell)?  Again thanks for your help.